# Is there a way to conditionally check if a window is using a scroll bar?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, mfc

In the application I am working on, 2 buttons are drawn onto the screen relative to a `CListBox` (let's call it `myListBox`) that sits directly to their left.

The buttons are placed according to values retrieved from `myListBox.GetClientRect()`. However, when scroll bars are present in `myListBox`, these buttons are incorrectly placed, since `GetClientRect` doesn't account for things such as scroll bars.

I'm curious if there is a conditional way in which I can check if a list box is currently using a scroll bar, if that makes sense. That way I can apply the difference to the function that moves my buttons so that I can achieve proper placement whether or not a scroll bar is present.

I tried `GetWindowRect`, but I suppose the window encapsulating the list box is much larger than the list box itself (in hindsight this is obvious).

```
if (scrollbarinfo.rgstate[0] == (STATE_SYSTEM_INVISIBLE || 
STATE_SYSTEM_UNAVAILABLE))
{
    visible = false;
}
```

Comment: GetWindowRect + MapWindowPoints is your answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`CWnd::GetScrollBarInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwnd-class?view=vs-2019#getscrollbarinfo) function and check `rgstate` member of its `SCROLLBARINFO` retrieved struct.

```cpp
SCROLLBARINFO sbi { };
LONG lScrollBar = OBJID_VSCROLL; //can also be OBJID_HSCROLL or OBJID_CLIENT
GetScrollBarInfo(lScrollBar, &sbi);

if (sbi.rgstate[0] & STATE_SYSTEM_INVISIBLE)
{
    //Scroll bar is not visible at the moment.
}
else if (sbi.rgstate[0] & STATE_SYSTEM_UNAVAILABLE)
{
    //Scrol bar is disabled, but might be visible.
}
```

Comment: I updated the post with a little snippet of my conditional code. I must have a big misunderstanding here of checking the rgstate, because visible will never evaluate to false. Any help?

Comment: @JimmyBlundell I updated my post with working snipped.

Answer (score 0):

For reference to anyone else who might see this post, this is what worked for me given my original code, taking into consideration what @Jovibor said:

```
int info = scrollbarinfo.rgstate[0];
if ((info & (STATE_SYSTEM_INVISIBLE | STATE_SYSTEM_UNAVAILABLE)) != 0)
{
visible = false;
}
```